# Field or View for selecting images attached to another selected node

Tags: nodes, entities, files, views

I have a content type of 'property' and have multiple file fields for attaching images.

I have a content type of 'flyer' where I have an entity reference field to select a property. I have this working. Next I need to display the files attached to that property and select one to be used in my 'flyer' content type. So selecting a new property in the select list should update my image choices.

I think this can be done with some combination of views contextual filters and relationships, but I don't understand it enough to get all the right pieces into the right places if it is indeed possible.

Do I need to create a custom module for a new field type or can this be done with what I've mentioned and if so please guide me how?

Comment: I think i've figured out how to display images of 'property' on the 'flyer' content add/edit node page. An entity reference widget view. Contextual filter: id from url. Relationship: referenced node. Add all image fields and use the relationship. The kicker was that I had to remove the filter of content type that the new view wizard added when I said I wanted to show property content. I guess this was filtering out the 'flyer' content type I was trying to access with the contextual filter.

Comment: I have these images showing up on the edit screen. But now I don't know how to select an image and assign it to a field. The images are just listed. I fear I'm almost there and will have to spend another day hunting for the 1 step I messed up. Only thing I can think to do is use javascript to copy image paths to hidden fields on click, but it's a very inelegant solution to something that I always thought was a Drupal strength. Any suggestions?